# Javascript create array lists from data with limit of 10

Tags: javascript

I have the following data and I need to create 2 arrays from the data. The data needs to look into the subcategory.

The first array would have all the subcategory names so in this case is would contain Subcat 1 and Subcat 2 and the second list would just count the number of subcatgory items which would be 2 in the case but with a limit of 10.

Here is the data:

```
var data = {

    "categories":[

        {
            "id":"661",
            "name": "some name",
            "subcategory": {
            "637": {
                "id": "637",
                "name": "Subcat 1",
                "translations": null
            },
            "638": {
                "id": "638",
                "name": "Subcat 2",
                "translations": null
            }
        },
        "image": "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6286b"
    };

]};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please share your effort?

Comment: please add the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two nested [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) loops and exit if the limit is reached.

```js
var data = { categories:[{ id:"661", name: "some name", subcategory: { 637: { id: "637", name: "Subcat 1", translations: null }, 638: { id: "638", name: "Subcat 2", translations: null } }, image: "73e043a7fae04b55855bede22da6286b" }] },
    subcategory = { names: [], count: 0 };

data.categories.some(function (c) {
    return Object.keys(c.subcategory).some(function (k) {
        subcategory.names.push(c.subcategory[k].name);
        subcategory.count++;
        return subcategory.count === 10;
    });
});

console.log(subcategory);
```